# OCIStmtPrepare returns always OCI_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c, oracle, oracle11g

When trying to execute a statement on Oracle RDBMS I always get `OCI_INVALID_HANDLE` as status (checked with gdb) and the statement therefore is not executed.

May someone could help to get this working:

```
OCIEnv* envh;
OCISvcCtx* svch;
OCIError* errh;
sword stat;
stat = OCIExtProcGetEnv (context, &envh, &svch, &errh);
OCIStmt* stmthp;

char errbuf[512];
sb4 errcode = 0;

char * cmd = "alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'";

sword status = OCIStmtPrepare(stmthp, errh, (const OraText*)cmd, (ub4) strlen(cmd), (ub4) OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);

if ( status != OCI_SUCCESS )
{
    OCIErrorGet((void*)errh, (ub4) 1, (text *) NULL, &errcode,
            (text*)errbuf, (ub4) sizeof(errbuf), OCI_HTYPE_ERROR);
    OCIExtProcRaiseExcpWithMsg((OCIExtProcContext*)context, errcode, (text*)errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));    
}
```

`context` is an `OCIExProcContext*` passed from PL/SQL to this external procedure

A simple `OCIExtProcRaiseExcpWithMsg((OCIExtProcContext*)context, 34, (text*)"custom", 6);` work without problems. Furthermore I checked all other pointer with gdb and they seem quite nice. May I missed some initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to allocate a statement handle. The variable `stmthp` you're passing into `OCIStmtPrepare` is not initialized:

```
sword status = OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *)envh, 
                 (dvoid **) &stmthp,
                 (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_STMT,  
                 (size_t) 0, 
                 (dvoid **) 0));
```